# Snort rule to see viber traffic

Tags: snort

I need help with the following 2 questions to create rules for snort.

1. Generate an alert when network traffic that indicates Viber, is being used.
2. Alert for any packet of size > 100 bytes from the network 172.20.0.0 with SNM
   255.240.0.0 designated to port 80.

Comment: Please provide more context: what language do you use, what versions, code snippets ore event reproducible examples

Comment: I'm using snort on ubuntu and kali and i want to see the traffic when viber is used. I have the port numbers for viber and the other one is to just get the alert when a packet size greater than 100 is passed using the network address given above in question

Answer (score 0):

a. Taken from https://commons.erau.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1477&context=jdfsl

- The analysis carried out in the work covers upto latest version of Viber 6.2.2 and all re- sults were verified for both android and iOS platforms.
- Viber usually communicates over UDP ports 7985, 7987, 5243 and 9785 for the voice calls 
  You will want to create, write rules that detect TCP and UDP traffic on these mentioned ports. for example.

So something like this then:
 - `alert udp any any -> $HOME_NET 7985 (msg: "Viber Traffic"; sid:10000001; rev: 1;)`

b. Ensure your $HOME_NET is setup correctly in your snort.conf, ergo which subnets you want to have under "home" $HOME_NET.
 - `alert tcp 172.20.0.0 any -> $HOME_NET 80 (msg: "Traffic from the 172.20.0.0 addr"; dsize:>100;sid:10000001; rev: 1;)`